# Local copy of object argument to CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda

I understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14857495/1613702), that arguments to a CUDA kernel are passed via constant memory (for compute capability 2.0 and higher) and, if modified, they are stored as local copies in either registers or on the stack. What happens if the argument is an object and only some of its members are modified by the kernel? Will the whole object have to be stored locally, or will copies be created only for the modified members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an interesting question I hadn't considered before, and the answer appears to be that only the used members of the structure are loaded to register (at least empirically based on exactly one example).

Consider the following contrived example:

```
struct parameters
{
    float w,x,y,z;
    int a,b,c,d;
};

__global__
void kernel(float *in, float *out, parameters p)
{
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    float val_in = in[tid];

    p.b += 10;
    p.w *= 2.0f;
    p.z /= 5.0f;

    out[tid] = (p.b>0) ? (p.w*val_in) : (p.z*val_in);
}
```

If the compiler only loads the parameters required, we should only see three 32 bit  parameter loads from `p` to register. The resulting PTX emitted by the compiler (Cuda 5.0 release compiler for sm_30) looks like this:

```
//
// Generated by NVIDIA NVVM Compiler
// Compiler built on Sat Sep 22 02:35:14 2012 (1348274114)
// Cuda compilation tools, release 5.0, V0.2.1221
//

.version 3.1
.target sm_30
.address_size 64

    .file   1 "/tmp/tmpxft_00000b1a_00000000-9_parameters.cpp3.i"
    .file   2 "/home/talonmies/parameters.cu"
    .file   3 "/opt/cuda-5.0/bin/../include/device_functions.h"

.visible .entry _Z6kernelPfS_10parameters(
    .param .u64 _Z6kernelPfS_10parameters_param_0,
    .param .u64 _Z6kernelPfS_10parameters_param_1,
    .param .align 4 .b8 _Z6kernelPfS_10parameters_param_2[32]
)
{
    .reg .pred  %p<2>;
    .reg .s32   %r<9>;
    .reg .f32   %f<8>;
    .reg .s64   %rd<8>;


    ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z6kernelPfS_10parameters_param_0];
    ld.param.u64    %rd2, [_Z6kernelPfS_10parameters_param_1];
    ld.param.f32    %f1, [_Z6kernelPfS_10parameters_param_2+12];
    ld.param.f32    %f2, [_Z6kernelPfS_10parameters_param_2];
    ld.param.u32    %r1, [_Z6kernelPfS_10parameters_param_2+20];
    cvta.to.global.u64  %rd3, %rd2;

///home/talonmies/parameters.cu:11     unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    .loc 2 11 1
    mov.u32     %r2, %ntid.x;
    mov.u32     %r3, %ctaid.x;
    mov.u32     %r4, %tid.x;
    mad.lo.s32  %r5, %r2, %r3, %r4;
    cvta.to.global.u64  %rd4, %rd1;

///home/talonmies/parameters.cu:12     float val_in = in[tid];
    .loc 2 12 1
    mul.wide.u32    %rd5, %r5, 4;
    add.s64     %rd6, %rd4, %rd5;

///home/talonmies/parameters.cu:14     p.b += 10;
    .loc 2 14 1
    add.s32     %r6, %r1, 10;

///home/talonmies/parameters.cu:15     p.w *= 2.0f;
    .loc 2 15 1
    add.f32     %f3, %f2, %f2;

///opt/cuda-5.0/bin/../include/device_functions.h:2399   return a / b;
    .loc 3 2399 3
    div.rn.f32  %f4, %f1, 0f40A00000;

///home/talonmies/parameters.cu:18     out[tid] = (p.b>0) ? (p.w*val_in) : (p.z*val_in);
    .loc 2 18 1
    setp.gt.s32     %p1, %r6, 0;
    selp.f32    %f5, %f3, %f4, %p1;

///home/talonmies/parameters.cu:12     float val_in = in[tid];
    .loc 2 12 1
    ld.global.f32   %f6, [%rd6];

///home/talonmies/parameters.cu:18     out[tid] = (p.b>0) ? (p.w*val_in) : (p.z*val_in);
    .loc 2 18 1
    mul.f32     %f7, %f5, %f6;
    add.s64     %rd7, %rd3, %rd5;
    st.global.f32   [%rd7], %f7;

///home/talonmies/parameters.cu:19 }
    .loc 2 19 2
    ret;
}
```

You can see that only `_Z6kernelPfS_10parameters_param_2` (which is `p.w`), `_Z6kernelPfS_10parameters_param_2+12`(which is `p.z`), and `_Z6kernelPfS_10parameters_param_2+20` (which is `p.b`) get loaded to registers. The other members of the structure are never loaded by the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer. I had suspected this from the small impact on register usage seen when passing large objects compared to small ones when only changing some of the members. If the results proves to be true in the general case, would there be any good reason for not passing larger objects of an existing class rather than creating a new smaller class?